# Ruby on Rails - Image Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add images to a model. I have Users set up with Devise and they `have_many` Items that they are selling.

I would now like to add an array of images to the Item model (not sure if this is the best approach).

I have looked a Paperclip but can only do one image. Also looked at carrier wave but not sure how to implement on existing model.

Here is some of my code.

**Item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :findItem, only: [:edit, :update, :sold]

  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.create(item_params)
    @item.user = current_user
    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "Your item was successfully listed."
      render 'show'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your item could not be listed. Please try again."
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      flash[:success] = "Your item listing was updated successfully."
      redirect_to item_path(@item)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your listing was not updated. Please try again."
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def sold
    @item.toggle(:sold)
    @item.save
    redirect_to item_path(@item)
  end

  private
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:title, :price, :description)
  end

  def findItem
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**Form for Item/new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <%= form_for(@item, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "What are you selling?", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :price %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.number_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Describe your item. The more detail you include, the more likely it is to sell." %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="center col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
      <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="center col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  <%= link_to "[ Cancel and return to listing page ]", items_path %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
   validates :title, :price, :description, presence: true
end

#app/models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item
   has_attached_file :picture
end
```

--

The above will allow you to create an `Item`, which will have any number of `images` that you want. You can pass the new `images` through `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @item = Item.new
      @item.images.build
   end

   def create
      @item = Item.new item_params
      @item.save
   end

   private

   def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(images_attributes: [:picture])
   end
end

#app/views/items/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :images do |i| %>
      <%= i.file_field :picture %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need. I will implement it tomorrow and see how it goes.  For the views would they be accessed with "@item.images.each" then iterate through?

Comment: If you wanted to *show* uploaded images, you'd have to use `@item.images.each do |image| <%= image_tag image.picture.url %> end` -- I could look at how you'd delegate the `picture.url` method to your images, but since it's `has_many`, it would be quite tricky

Answer (score 2):

You simply want to create an Image model. And set the relation with Item as follows: `Item` `has_many :images`, and `Image` `belongs_to :item`.

But, yeah, paperclip is a good start.

**EDIT**: Oh, and welcome Rails, you will find a good community ready to help. You might also find useful to search for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` so you can have the images uploaded in your Item form and `cocoon` to dynamically add and remove images on the item's form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So am I correct in assuming I would create the association much the same as associating an "item" with a "user"? I will head to Google now and research "accepts_nested_attributes_for" and "cocoon".

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Marked this question as resolved once you know we've answered your original question. If you have new questions, just create new questions with the specific problem you have.